# Created a calculator that calculates perimeter and area of rectangle, why doesn't it display the area and perimeter?

Tags: java

I created a calculator that solves the perimeter and area of a rectangle when you give it the measurements of two sides. However, I cannot get the code to make it say "Area =" and "Perimeter =" even though I wrote it??

Here is my code:

````
import java.util.Scanner;

class Rectangle
{
    static int n;
    static int m;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the width:");
    n = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the length:");
    m = s.nextInt();
    }
    public int solveArea;
    {
        int Area; 
        Area=n*m;
        System.out.println("Area = " + Area);
    }
    public int solvePerimeter;
    {   
        int Perimeter; 
        Perimeter = 2*(m+n);
        System.out.println("Perimeter = " + Perimeter);
    }
    
            
            }
    ```
````

Comment: Your code has syntax errors and it won't compile.

Comment: the code needs to be in a method and the methods needs to be called. is solveArea a method? if yes, then remove the semi colon

Comment: The method definitions are not correct. `public int solveArea(int n, int m)` and `public int solvePerimeter(int n, int m)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parentheses after the method names and make them `void` as they don't return anything and `static` so they can access the `static` members, `n` and `m`, and can be invoked in the `main` method directly (i.e. without using the instance reference). Check [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) to learn more about it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the width:");
    n = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the length:");
    m = s.nextInt();
    solveArea();
    solvePerimeter();
}

public static void solveArea() {
    int Area;
    Area = n * m;
    System.out.println("Area = " + Area);
}

public static void solvePerimeter() {
    int Perimeter;
    Perimeter = 2 * (m + n);
    System.out.println("Perimeter = " + Perimeter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You see the compiler runs only the main method by default, you need to call your custom-defined methods in the main method to actually execute them.
In your case, you need to call `solveArea` and `solvePerimeter` in the main function.
By the way, your code won't run because it has a lot of syntactical errors.